# Leaflet Maps with Custom Tiles Zoom offset x y

Tags: c#, leaflet

I'm trying to use leaflet to render large images using x,y coordinates like so:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
   crs: L.CRS.Simple,
   attributionControl: false,
   reuseTiles:true, 
}).setView([0, 0], 1);
```

The problem is that when I zoom I seem to get an offset. So as I continually zoom in the map appears to shift.

I am drawing the image on the backend using C# and GDI+ so it's quite possible that I am getting code this wrong:

```
 private void DrawLine(int x, int y, int z, int squareSize, Graphics g, Shape shape, Pen drawPen)
    {
        Line line = (Line)shape;

        var scalingFactor = 0.1;
        var zoom = (z * (scalingFactor));

        double startScaledX = (line.StartPoint.X * zoom) + ((squareSize * -1) * x);
        double startScaledY = (line.StartPoint.Y * -1 * zoom) + ((squareSize * -1) * y);
        double endScaledX = (line.EndPoint.X * zoom) + ((squareSize * -1) * x);
        double endScaledY = (line.EndPoint.Y * -1 * zoom) + ((squareSize * -1) * y);

        var width = Math.Abs(endScaledX - startScaledX);
        var height = Math.Abs(endScaledY - startScaledY);

        var startPoint = new System.Drawing.PointF((float)startScaledX, (float)startScaledY);
        var endPoint = new System.Drawing.PointF((float)endScaledX, (float)endScaledY);
        var rectDrawBounds = (new RectangleF((float)startScaledX, (float)startScaledY, (float)width, (float)height));
        var rectTileBounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 256, 256);

        g.DrawLine(drawPen, startPoint, endPoint);

    }
```

I have noticed that if I zoom in and out at [0,0] then the zoom works perfectly. Everything else seems to shift the map.

I would appreciate any help that you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

In Leaflet's `L.CRS.Simple`, the map scale grows by a factor of 2 every zoom level. In other words:

```
scale = 2**z;
```

or

```
scale = Math.pow(2,z);
```

or

```
scale = 1<<z;
```

or

> At zoom level 0, a 256-pixel tile covers 256 map units. One map unit spans over 1 pixel.
>
> At zoom level 1, a 256-pixel tile covers 128 map units. One map unit spans over 2 pixels.
>
> At zoom level 2, a 256-pixel tile covers 64 map units. One map unit spans over 4 pixels.
>
> At zoom level *n*, a 256-pixel tile covers 256/2<sup>*n*</sup> map units. One map unit spans over 2<sup>*n*</sup> pixels.

For reference, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/crs/CRS.Simple.js

Fix your `z`, `scalingFactor` and `zoom` calculations and relationships accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont solve the problem. Sure the zoom factor will be better but the map is shifting. I think this might have something to do with projection but I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope. If you fix the scale, the coordinates will match between zoom levels and it won't "shift", I've seen variations of this happening. You might want to use a debug gridlayer like in https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wuna/edit?html,output to help with the debugging.

Comment: @IvanSanchez link is dead, do you maybe have a different one?